# Can't fix page layout in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

Hi I've got a website up.

I'm a no0b but I learn fast and I learn as I go.

However in one of the pages...the footer has gone up too close to the header.  I want the area between the header and the footer fixed.  I've tried changing the height of the main content in css but it doesn't seem to work.  The front main page is ok.  It's the about me page I'm having difficulty with.  I just want the space between the header and footer fixed regardless of what's between them.

I use:

```
#site_content {
    width: 950px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of my page]

thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please provide us the website link ? so that i can have look at the problem...

Comment: Hi it's http://themachine-mk1.org.uk/about.html

Please bear in mind it's an incomplete website.

Comment: Check out the link http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/vrb2yzLn/

Comment: hey let us know, Whether it helped or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey just replace your footer code by the below code

**CSS**

```
footer {
width: 100%;             /* make width 100% changes done*/
font: normal 100% arial, sans-serif;
padding: 50px 20px 5px 0;
text-align: right;
background: transparent;
position: fixed;            /*changes done*/
bottom: 0;                 /*changes done*/
top: auto;                /*changes done*/
text-align: center;       /*changes done*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That seems to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `#footer` selector in your CSS:

```
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get an idea about how to do it by inspecting this template from twitter bootstrap:
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer.html

BTW: Twitter Bootstap may result interesting to you (based on the screenshot you show).